# Remove duplicate row based on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two select statements which is returning duplicated data. What I'm trying to accomplish is to remove a duplicated leg. But I'm having hard times to get to the second row programmatically.

```
select i.InvID, i.UID, i.StartDate, i.EndDate, i.Minutes,i.ABID from inv_v i, InvoiceLines_v i2 where 
i.Period = '2014/08'
and i.EndDate = i2.EndDate
and i.Minutes = i2.Minutes
and i.Uid <> i2.Uid
and i.abid = i2.abid
order by i.EndDate
```

This select statement returns the following data.

[image]

As you can see it returns duplicate rows where `minutes` are the same `ABID` is the same but `InvID` are different. What I need to do is to remove one of the `InvID` where the criteria matches. Doesn't matter which one.

The second select statement is returning different data.

```
select i.InvID,  i.UID, i.StartDate, i.EndDate, i.Minutes from InvoiceLines_v i, InvoiceLines_v i2 where 
i.Period = '2014/08'
and i.EndDate = i2.EndDate
and i.Uid = i2.Uid
and i.Abid <> i2.Abid 
and i.Language <> i2.Language
order by i.startdate desc
```

[image]

In this select statement I want to remove an `InvID` where `UID` is the same then select the lowest `Mintues`. In This case, I would remove the following InvIDs: `2537676` , `2537210`

My goal is to remove those rows...

I could accomplish this using `cursor` grab the `InvID` and remove it by simple delete statement, but I'm trying to stay away from cursors.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Cursors is the only way I know how to accomplish this, but I can't use it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` to delete all duplicates except the one with the highest `InvID` by deleting those rows where another row exists with the same values but with a higher `InvID`

```
delete from inv_v 
where exists (
    select 1 from inv_v i2
    where i2.InvID > inv_v.InvID
    and i2.minutes = inv_v.minutes
    and i2.EndDate = inv_v.EndDate
    and i2.abid = inv_v.abid
    and i2.uid <> inv_v.uid -- not sure why <> is used here, copied from question
)
```

Comment: Perfect. It works if I do a `select` statement. `select from inv_v i where exists ...` However, when I do `delete from inv_v i ...` I get this error `Incorrect syntax near where`...

Comment: I fixed the issue. I simply removed the `i` from `delete from inv_v` and in the second select statement I used `inv_v` instead of `i1. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problems regarding duplicate data and some one told me to use partition by and other methods but those were causing performance issues
However , I had a primary key in my table through which I was able to select one row from the duplicate data and then delete it.

For example in the first select statement "minutes" and "ABID" are the criteria to consider duplicacy in data.But "Invid" can be used to distinguish between the duplicate rows.

So you can use below query to remove duplicacy.

```
  delete from inv_i where inv_id in (select max(inv_id) from inv_i group by minutes,abid having count(*) > 1 );
```

This simple concept was helpful to me. It can be helpful in your case if "Inv_id" is unique.

Comment: The concept is simple. And yes, `inv_id` is unique key in the table. The problem is that the data you see in the image is returned by that whole select statement. I had to write that `where` statement to get the data as it displayed in the image. I cannot assume that if `Minutes` and `ABID` are the same remove one. I can assume that however, if I get the data from the above `select` statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
 SELECT InvID
      ,[UID]
      ,StartDate
      ,EndDate
      ,[Minutes] 
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY InvID, [UID] ORDER BY [Minutes] ASC) rn 
 FROM InvoiceLines_v  
 )
SELECT *
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I update your code to include my `where` statement. I have to have that where statement in order for me to grab and display the data as it shows in picture2. The only issue I have is all the rows have `rn=1` At least two of the rows should have a different number so I could remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ORIGINAL_TABLE with your table name.

QUERY 1:

```
  WITH DUP_TABLE AS
             (
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (PARTITION BY minutes, ABID ORDER BY minutes, ABID) As ROW_NO
              FROM <ORIGINAL_TABLE>
             )
 DELETE FROM DUP_TABLE WHERE ROW_NO > 1;
```

QUERY 2:

```
  WITH DUP_TABLE AS
             (
              SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
              OVER (PARTITION BY UID ORDER BY minutes) As ROW_NO
              FROM <ORIGINAL_TABLE>
             )
 DELETE FROM DUP_TABLE WHERE ROW_NO > 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In order for me to get the data as it displayed in the first and second image I HAVE TO have the `where` statement. Otherwise, the data will not be displayed properly and the `Row_No` will be reflected accurately.